# What is the difference between % and %% in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

In bash scripting, when `t="hello.txt"` both

`${t%%.txt}` and `${t%.txt}` returns `"hello"`

the same goes for `${t##*.}` and `${t#*.}` returns `"txt"`.

Is there a difference between them? How do they work?

Comment: These forms of *parameter expansion* are generally termed *parameter expansion with substring removal*. `#` - trims from the left, up to, and including the end of the specified match. `%` - trims from the right. (details in answers below)

Comment: Note that `%` and `%%` are also used in the format string for the `printf` builtin and have a different and unrelated meaning.  (added in case the title misdirects someone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, `%%` removes as much as possible, `%` as little as possible.

```
# t="hello.world.txt"
# echo ${t%.*}
hello.world
# echo ${t%%.*}
hello
```

From the bash manual:

```
'${PARAMETER%WORD}'
'${PARAMETER%%WORD}'
     The WORD is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
     expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the
     expanded value of PARAMETER, then the result of the expansion is
     the value of PARAMETER with the shortest matching pattern (the '%'
     case) or the longest matching pattern (the '%%' case) deleted.  If
     PARAMETER is '@' or '*', the pattern removal operation is applied
     to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
     resultant list.  If PARAMETER is an array variable subscripted with
     '@' or '*', the pattern removal operation is applied to each member
     of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```

Answer (score 1):

`${string%substring}`
Deletes shortest match of `$substring` from back of `$string`.

For example:

```
# Rename all filenames in $PWD with "TXT" suffix to a "txt" suffix.
# For example, "file1.TXT" becomes "file1.txt" . . .

SUFF=TXT
suff=txt

for i in $(ls *.$SUFF)
do
  mv -f $i ${i%.$SUFF}.$suff
  #  Leave unchanged everything *except* the shortest pattern match
  #+ starting from the right-hand-side of the variable $i . . .
done ### This could be condensed into a "one-liner" if desired.
```

`${string%%substring}`
Deletes longest match of `$substring` from back of `$string`.

```
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc
#                    ||     shortest
#        |------------|     longest

echo ${stringZ%b*c}      # abcABC123ABCa
# Strip out shortest match between 'b' and 'c', from back of $stringZ.

echo ${stringZ%%b*c}     # a
# Strip out longest match between 'b' and 'c', from back of $stringZ.
```

Comment: You can surround your inline code with backticks and have the format of ${string%substring} be formatted as `${string%substring}`. Very good effort on the answer. (but Benjamin beat you too it `:)`